# how to create auto scale rule for HttpQueueLength with az monitor

Tags: azure-cli, azure-monitoring

I can create basic auto sacle rule such as memory easily

```
az monitor autoscale rule create -g xx --autoscale-name xxxx --scale out 2 --condition "CpuPercentage > 60 avg 1m"
```

But I want to create a rule base on Http Queue Length or Http5xx error, then az monitor command throws error

```
az monitor autoscale rule create -g xx --autoscale-name xxxx --scale out 2 --condition "HttpQueueLength <= 1 sum 1m" 

az monitor autoscale rule create -g xx --autoscale-name xxxx --scale out 2 --condition "Http5xx <= 50 sum 1m"
```

Error is:

```
--condition ["NAMESPACE"] METRIC {==,!=,>,>=,<,<=} THRESHOLD {avg,min,max,total,count} PERIOD
            [where DIMENSION {==,!=} VALUE [or VALUE ...]
            [and   DIMENSION {==,!=} VALUE [or VALUE ...] ...]]
```

Can someone guide me?

Comment: I just realised that azure cli doesn't support sum in condition (Only support count, min, max, avg, total). What is the difference between sum, count and total?

Answer (score 0):

**Sum** – the sum of all values captured over the aggregation interval. Sometimes referred to as the Total aggregation.

**[Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/aggregations#counts)** – the number of measurements captured over the aggregation interval. Count doesn't look at the value of the measurement, only the number of records.

**[Total](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported)** tends to refer to the total for a given criteria (total requests, total jobs, etc.)

Refer [supported metrics link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-supported) , and [Explained metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-aggregation-explained) for further more information.